# How to change muitl divs the display which have some special id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I has some div as follows

```
<div id="span1"></div>
<div id="span3"></div>
<div id="span5"></div>
<div id="span7"></div>
.....
```

There is "span" in the id, How to show or hide them by jquery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick, if I understand the question correctly.

```
$('[id*="span"]').hide();
```

That said, a much BETTER approach would be to put a class on all the elements you want to manipulate with the same code then use the class to hide the elements as a group.

```
<div id="span1" class"span"></div>
<div id="span3" class"span"></div>
<div id="span5" class"span"></div>
<div id="span7" class"span"></div>

$('div.span').hide();
```

This is much cleaner.

Comment: +1 for using the `*=`, but wouldn't `^=` do the same? assuming they all start in `span`

Comment: Thanks! one more question ,  `function category_select(id){
 hide/show some div} `, How to pass id param to  string '[id*="/param/"]' ?

Comment: @Joseph - I was playing it safe. The OP said that span was "in" the ID so I wasn't sure we could count on it being a prefix.

Comment: @why I think you should post a separate question for that. The format of this site works better that way. In any case. Go with the second option it is a much better approach anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672033/how-to-pass-js-code-to-string-gracefully  it's here

Answer (score 5):

you can put the selectors of the ones to hide in an array and join then with a comma:

```
var tohide = [
    "#span1",
    "#span3",
    "#span5",
    "#span7"
];

$(tohide.join(',')).hide();
```

---

or, add a common class to each:

```
<div class="tohide" id="span1"></div>
<div class="tohide" id="span3"></div>
<div class="tohide" id="span5"></div>
<div class="tohide" id="span7"></div>

$('.tohide').hide();
```

Comment: +1 - Very clever solution. Thinking outside the box today are you?

Comment: Actually, you don't even need `.join(',')`, `toString()` is enough. But clever solution!