# How to pass js code to string gracefully?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is my code

```
<input type="radio" name="category" id="elementary" value="elementary" /> 1
<input type="radio" name="category" id="junior" value="junior" /> 2
<input type="radio" name="category" id="senior" value="senior" /> 3
<input type="radio" name="category" id="university" value="university" /> 4
<input type="radio" name="category" id="profession"/> 5

<div id='grade_select' class="clearfix">
  <div id='elementary_grade' class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id='junior_grade' class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id='senior_grade' class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id='university_grade' class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id='profession_grade' class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I want:

When check one radio, need to hide all the div in grade_select, and then show the div which id include the current radio value

There is my js code , I do not know how to going on

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
      $( "input[name='category']" ).bind( "click", category_select)
    });
    function category_select(){
        $("div:[id=this.attr[id]]).show()
    }
    </script>
```

**FYI:** This question is a spinoff of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671865/how-to-change-muitl-divs-the-display-which-have-some-special-id).

Comment: Why don't you explain what this code is doing, what the error is, and what you expect it to do? Right now, you're only telling us what you want it to do. Also, there is a missing quote in your CSS selector in the category_select function. :)

Comment: Uh, we don't do homework on stackoverflow....

Comment: @Christian - Unfortunately it appears we do (See below).

Comment: Best of it, they don't even describe what they're doing. Talking about clueless questions and even more clueless answers. At least one hopes they work...

Comment: Sorry @jmort253 , I do not know how to going on , so I do know what error it will be

Comment: You didn't run the code? Seems like that would be the first thing to do before asking questions. Kind of a moot point now though. It looks like Parth answered your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I am one server side programmer, I plan to finish one site myself :)

Comment: @Christian, I don't think it'll be appropriate to call this homework - if you don't know something, how can you do it? This doesn't mean I support the questions which ARE actually for homework...just that to me this one seemed wrongly classified by you

Comment: @JohnFx, the previous one's also for you.

Comment: I doubt this is homework. I think it is just an example of a programmer who isn't interested in putting any effort into figuring it out on their own and wants it spoon fed to them.

Comment: @ParthThakkar I called it "homework" metaphorically in the sense of the OP having some code which he didn't do himself and is expecting others to fix it for him.

Comment: @Christian, I have already got my answer. If you have enough time , I think you could fix your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728280/browser-automatically-looks-up-image-url-from-js-source

Comment: @why How is my question remotely related?

Comment: @Christian, I think we can close this topic, I have some important works need to fix :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $( "input[name='category']" ).bind( "click", function() {
            $("#grade_select div").hide().parent().find( '#' + this.id + "_grade" ).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `.find( this.id + "_grade" )` won't find anything. You need a `#` in the selector.

Comment: Not a big deal, but you traverse the DOM twice.

Comment: @Guffa...again made a silly mistake as i usually do...i'll just edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("input[name='category']").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("div#grade_select > div").hide();
    $("#" + id + "_grade").show();  
});​
```

### Demo

Comment: Please my dear friend, don't use jQuery to get the `id` of a DOM element. `$(this).attr('id');` => `this.id` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='category']").click(function(){
    $("#grade_select div").hide().filter('#' + this.id + '_grade').show();
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EnwVb/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable holding the ID first and then use that as the selector:

```
function category_select() {
     var $this = $(this),
     id = '#' + $this.attr('id') + '_grade'; // calculate ID of element to show

     $('#grade_select')
         .children() // select all children
         .hide() // hide all children
         .filter(id) // select the right one
         .show(); // and show it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector `#grade_select > div` to hide all divs that are immediate children (so that you can have other divs inside them if you like), then filter out the one that you want to show:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $("input[name=category]").click(function(){
    $("#grade_select > div").hide().filter("#" + this.id + "_grade").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbDgd/)

**jquery code**

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    $("#grade_select div").hide();
    $("#" + this.id + "_grade").show();
});​
```

Comment: @gdoron bruvnic :)) hows it, ha ha neah Thanks for that day man - helped me to stop the bad habit, if you ever came to this part of the world then I will buy you a coffee, <cheers> :P ha ha {cold here though - bit unwell indeed}